# Azure DevOps System Access Token Scope

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to run a pipeline to clone my repos of 2 organizations. With a PAT it works well, but when I use the system access token only repos of the organization from where the pipeline runs are cloned. For other repos of the second organization I get the following error:

fatal: Cannot prompt because terminal prompts have been disabled.
fatal: could not read Password ...

So the question, can the system access account be cross organizations ?

Answer (score 0):

By default personal access token (PAT) is restricted to Organization scope. So when a PAT is created it has that Organization scope. But, you can overcome this by enabling in Organization settings to allow specific people or groups to create global PAT.
[PAT for all organization scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82BGd.png)

Although this is not a recommended approach keeping in mind security concerns.

Comment: With a PAT I've no problem, it works. The issue appears when I try to use System.AccessToken instead of a PAT.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer. The system access token cannot be across organization.  It can be scoped for projects within the same organization or for the whole organization from where the pipeline runs.